# Copying "this" pointer to a buffer

Tags: c++, pointers

I need to copy the address of `this` pointer to a buffer and re-typecast it elsewhere. I am aware that I can do it, if I do it outside the class. But,here I specifically need to use some member function as given in the sample code provided here:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

class MyClass
{
public:
    MyClass(const int & i)
    {
        id = i;
    }
    ~MyClass()
    {

    }
    void getAddress(char* address)
    {
        memcpy(address, this, sizeof(this));        
    }
    void print() const
    {
        std::cout<<" My id: "<<id<<std::endl;           
    }

private:
    int id; 
};

int main()
{
    MyClass myClass(100);
    std::cout<<"myClass: "<<&myClass<<std::endl; 
    myClass.print();

    // Need to copy the address to a buffer, sepcifically using a function as follows and retrieve it later
    char tmp[128];
    myClass.getAddress(tmp);

    // retreiving the pointer   
    MyClass* myClassPtr = (MyClass*) tmp;
    std::cout<<"myClassPtr: "<<myClassPtr<<std::endl;
    myClassPtr->print();

    return 0;
}
```

My Output:

```
myClass: 0x7fff22d369e0
 My id: 100
myClassPtr: 0x7fff22d369f0
 My id: 100
```

As we can see two addresses are different. However, both function are printing the id correctly. I wonder how this happens! I also need the correct method.

Comment: You can also use `std::addressof` to get the address of an instance with overloaded address operator. Also, no need to have `char tmp[128]`.. Change it to `char tmp[sizeof(void*)]` or just make a pointer to it.. Why do you need a "buffer"..

Comment: Are you wanting the *address* copied, or the *contents* at that address copied? These are two separate things.

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but do you really need the extra stuff that `std::endl` does? `'\n'` ends a line.

Comment: @crashmstr: I need the address to be copied.

Comment: `MyClass* myClassPtr = &myClass;`? If you have the *address* you are pointing to the same object and there is nothing funky or tricky about that (other than making sure what you point to has not gone out of scope or...)

Comment: @Brandon: I need to send the address to a separate place where I need to refer and use the same object.

Comment: @KonstantinL: &this not allowed. Compiler throws the following error. error: lvalue required as unary ‘&’ operand
   memcpy(address, &this, sizeof(this));

Comment: I meant `memcpy(address, this, sizeof(this));` does not copy `this` pointer.

Comment: @KonstantinL: You are right. Could you see any work around for this?

Comment: `const MyClass* tmp = this; memcpy(address, &tmp, sizeof(this));`

Comment: @Soo I suggest you show a better version of what you are really trying to do. If the receiving end needs to use the object, it needs to know the type, and passing a "buffer" is just a strange way to do this without more information.

Comment: @crashmstr: I agree with you. But in my application, I need to send it to a different thread and the message passing is using a buffer.

Comment: You can't have an address of 'this' as it is a keyword and not actually stored in memory. You probably need an address of the object which is the value of 'this'.

Comment: @Sergei: But I should be able to copy the value of "this" to some buffer...right?

Comment: @Soo you buffer really needs to be void* tmp; and not char[]. In your myClassPtr you are really printing the address of the local variable tmp[].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct version of `getAddress()`:

```
void getAddress(char* address)
{
    const MyClass* tmp = this;
    memcpy(address, &tmp, sizeof(this));
}
```

Update:

```
// retreiving the pointer   
// MyClass* myClassPtr = (MyClass*) tmp; - wrong
MyClass* myClassPtr = *( (MyClass**) tmp );
```

Comment: this will be an address of a local variable. Nothing to do with 'this'.

Comment: Actually, this will copy the value of 'this'. I downvoted by mistake.

Comment: @Soo, check better.

Comment: @KonstantinL: My program with your suggestion again gives wrong results! Can you please confirm?

Comment: Oh, I missed another bug in the original code.Updated.

Comment: @KonstantinL: That was awesome! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You are not copying the value of the `this` pointer, but the data that the pointer is pointing to (`memcpy` expects the address of the data to copy).

The correct syntax would be:

```
MyClass*  ptr = this;
memcpy(address, &ptr, sizeof(ptr));
```

That is why you get the same/correct output at the end.

Then, the assignment

```
MyClass* myClassPtr = (MyClass*) tmp;
```

is wrong too, you set the pointer to the same address as the char buffer, **not** to the address that is stored in the char buffer.

A possible solution could look like this:

```
MyClass* myClassPtr;
memcpy( &myClassPtr, tmp, sizeof( MyClass*));
```

Finally: I'd like to know what exactly you want to do, that you want to implement something like this? Maybe this is the solution for this problem, but I have a strong feeling that this is the wrong solution for the real problem ...

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I need to send the address of "this" object to some other thread using a buffer (a character array). The receiving thread will cast it again back and do some operation on the object. If you have a better solution, please let me know.

Comment: I have an Inter Thread message passing scheme which accepts std::vector<char> as the input. So I need to pass everything using this buffer, if I want to send something to another thread. In the situation explained in my question, I need to send "this" pointer to some other thread using this Inter Thread Message which accepts only std::vector<char>. This is the reason behind my requirement.